# Copy data from one dataframe into the column of another dataframe depending on 'n' conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
                 df1
        date     hour      var1
0   2017-05-01  00:00:00   456585
1   2017-05-01  01:00:00   899875
2   2017-05-01  02:00:00   569566
3   2017-05-01  03:00:00   458756
4   2017-05-01  04:00:00   231458
5   2017-05-01  05:00:00   986545

                 df2
        date     hour      var2
0   2017-05-01  00:00:00   456585
1   2017-05-01  01:00:00   899875
2   2017-05-01  02:00:00   569566
3   2017-05-01  03:00:00   458756
4   2017-05-01  04:00:00   231458
5   2017-05-01  05:00:00   986545
```

Here are my two dataframes, I need to find a way that will allow me to transplant the column **'var2'** from **df2** and **insert** as a new column in **df1** so that the dates and hours will match up.

Obviously how the dataframes look now I could just insert it and it would line up, but lets assume that the data is not aligned perfectly and would need some sort of conditional approach and transplant.

How would I go about this?

**EDIT:**
Solved it using pandas merge as mentioned below!

```
index_vals = ['date', 'hour']
merged_inner = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on=index_vals, right_on=index_vals)
```

Comment: You need to investigate `pandas.merge`

Comment: Can you put that as the answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Honestly Im not sure that the question should remain on SO as it is a duplicate. The question has been answered many times before. I will vote to close.